# hostname -i returns strange result in linux

Tags: linux, centos, hostname, hosts, ifconfig

If I run below command, I am getting some strange IP addresses.

```
hostname -i
198.105.244.11 198.105.254.11
```

My host file entry is in default configuration, below are the contents of my /etc/hosts file entry

```
 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Actual IP of this machine is `192.168.2.31`

I hope, once I added below entry in `/etc/hosts` file,

```
 192.168.2.31   myhost
```

I might get expected output,

```
 hostname -i
 192.168.2.31
```

But, Why its showing different range of IPs while running `hostname -i`?

Update:

```
ip r

192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.31 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0

ifconfig eth0

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ##removed##  
          inet addr:192.168.2.31  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feca:24c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2153703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:612859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:189727756 (180.9 MiB)  TX bytes:761146814 (725.8 MiB)
```

(Using Cent 6.4)

Comment: Can you post output of ifconfig or "ip a" also.

Comment: Also make sure you have full name of the host (FQDN) in the hosts file

Comment: Can you use `hostname -I` instead, or do you want to understand the results of `hostname -i` ?  Note from man page: "Avoid using this option; use hostname -I instead".  With a quick test on *my* centos6 system, `hostname -i` returns an IP address which does not match the machine on which it is running.

Comment: @user4556274, I could see if I am using ``-I``. And yes, why its showing some other IPs. As per StefanR answer, I have done the dig and getting those IPs. But, while other host is showing expected result using ``-i`` I am confused.

Comment: @Spike did you notice my answer?

Comment: @jlliagre, yes, i noticed. Do i need to restart interface after the change?

Comment: No, you shouldn't

Comment: I mean, you don't need to restart the interface. You might restart it if you want but it is not necessary.

Comment: @jlliagre, you mean to say ``hosts:      dns files`` should be ``hosts:      files dns``? If so, its not working after changing / restarting also.

Comment: Is there still `192.168.2.31   myhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file, and does `hostname` returns `myhost` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have previous DNS a records in the DNS server you are using for that hostname.
YOu can verify this with dig:

```
dig <your.host.name>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a trick from your DNS server. Querying whatever unknown hostname/fqdn will return precisely the two IP addresses you get:

```
$ nslookup whatever-unknown-name 4.2.2.2
Server:     4.2.2.2
Address:    4.2.2.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   whatever-unknown-name
Address: 198.105.244.11
Name:   whatever-unknown-name
Address: 198.105.254.11
```

Your server is configured to query first the DNS then look at the /etc/hosts files so whatever you put in the latter is be ignored if your DNS server is resolving your hostname. The issue is it is fooling you by "resolving" any unknown name to the fixed IP addresses you got.

To fix the issue, edit your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file and put `files` before `dns` in the `hosts` line.