# Understanding why hostname -i returns strange IP address

Tags: linux, centos, dns, hostname, hosts

I am referencing the following question because it's similar but not the same:

- [hostname -i returns strange result in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306364/hostname-i-returns-strange-result-in-linux)

On my CentOS 7 system, I get a strange IP address from "hostname -i" after I change my hostname, and I am trying to figure out why this is the case.

I change the hostname with following command:

```
# hostnamectl set-hostname saturn
# systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed
```

My /etc/hosts file shows:

```
 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

The following is in my /etc/nsswistch.conf file:

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

My server IP address is 192.168.1.13, but "hostname -i" returns strange a IP address:

```
# hostname -i
92.242.140.21
```

However, "hostname -I" is fine:

```
# hostname -I
192.168.1.13
```

Why does hostname -i return 92.242.140.21. Is it a random dynamic IP assigned to my system by the DNS? Can someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher It's the default configuration on CentOS 7, I just left it there. Does it affect the hostname command? According to this, it's only used as fallback: https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/nss-myhostname/. Also, hostname -f returns "saturn".

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/587895/10473

Comment: what happens with `ping saturn`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike the `hostname -I` command, which just lists all configured IP addresses on all network interfaces, the `hostname -i` command performs name resolution (see the `hostname` man page).

Since your newly assigned hostname cannot be resolved using the `/etc/hosts` file, running `hostname -i` will cause your system's name resolver to generate a DNS query to an external DNS server. At this server (which I presume belongs to your ISP), this query comes up empty (NXDOMAIN result: i.e. non-existent domain). Because your ISP has partnered up with Barefruit, rather than receiving the NXDOMAIN result, you receive a Barefruit IP address in response to your query:

```
$ dig +short -x 92.242.140.21
unallocated.barefruit.co.uk.
```

I imagine that adding your new hostname to your `/etc/hosts` file will make the weird Barefruit IP address disappear when you run the `hostname -i` command. If not, you may disregard this answer : )

---

Just for the fun of it: using the `dig` command, you can interrogate different name servers. To see the difference in response, you could run the following two commands:

```
$ dig saturn
$ dig @8.8.8.8 saturn
```

The first causes name resolution via your system's preconfigured DNS server, and likely results in a Barefruit IP address being returned. The second command asks [Google Public DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) to resolve the name, and returns with an NXDOMAIN status. Or not?

If so, your ISP may be involved in the dubious practice of [DNS hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking), and you may want to figure out if there is an opt-out possibility, or change your DNS service provider.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I tried everything you suggested and and the results are as you said. I accepted your answer. One quick question. How do edit the /etc/hosts file so that the barefruit IP address disappears? How should I add "saturn" into the /etc/hosts? Should it be on a new line, different from the localhost? What's the rule of thumb for editing the /etc/hosts file?

Comment: @s2000coder Indeed, that is what you could do. E.g. enter a new line reading something like `192.168.1.13   saturn` (assuming you have a static local IP address). Otherwise, you could just add 'saturn'  to the lines already listed in your hosts file starting with 127.0.0.1 and ::1. See `man hosts` for the rules of thumb.